# обновление записи открывающегося окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Стоит задача открыть окно и записать значение, если окно закрыто, и переписать значение, если окно открыто.

Значение для записи в окно извлекается из self.list_1 с помощью:

```
person = self.list_1.curselection().
```

self.list_1-экземпляр Listbox. При выполнении функции возникает следующее исключение:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'curselection'.

В чем моя ошибка?

```
def tasks_window_call(self, event):
  try:
    self.tasks_window_entry.delete(0)
    person = self.list_1.curselection()
    self.tasks_windows_entry.insert(0, self.current_results_list[person[0]])
  except AttributeError:
    self.open_tasks_window()
    person = self.list_1.curselection()
    self.tasks_windows_entry.insert(0, self.current_results_list[person[0]])
```

Comment: Вероятно, `list` объект, но не типа `Listbox`. В примере, кстати, никакого `list` не имеется, а имеется `list_1`

Comment: self.list_1 = Listbox(frame_1, selectmode=EXTENDED). person = self.list_1.curselection()-при выполнении этой инструкции и возникает исключение.

Comment: @vladionair, приведите код, где у вас создается экземпляр self.list_1

Comment: self.list_1 = Listbox(frame_1, selectmode=EXTENDED)

Comment: Где? В каком месте вы создаете и инициализируете list_1. Поймите, чудес не бывает - эту программу пишете вы, а не питон, и интерпретатор ругается не просто так

Comment: да,конечно, все так... ошибка найдена, всем спасибо!;)